# Click interceptor directive

Tags: angular.js, coffeescript

I needed a simple way to add this test to certain click events:

```
if isUser then fireClickEvent else openSignInModal
```

So I made this directive:

```
angular.module 'openLETS.core.lib.guestLock', []
.directive 'authGuestLock', ($compile, $state, olString, Auth) ->

  ######### Private #########
  restrict = 'A'
  priority = 1
  terminal = true

  link = (scope, elem, attrs) ->
    $compile(elem.contents())(scope) # Terminal breaks translate, this is a workaround
    elem.on 'click', (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
      if scope.currentUser
        if attrs.ngClick then scope.$eval attrs.ngClick
        if attrs.uiSref
          params = scope.$eval olString.objFrom attrs.uiSref
          state = olString.until attrs.uiSref, '('
          $state.go state, params
      else
        Auth.openModal 'signUp'


  ######### Config #########
  restrict: restrict
  link: link
  priority: priority
  terminal: terminal
```

What do you think of it's readability and functionality?

This can be made generic quite easily by passing the condition and fallback expressions to the directive:

```
angular.module 'openLETS.core.lib.clickInterceptor', []
.directive 'clickInterceptor', ($compile, $state, olString, Auth) ->

  ######### Private #########
  restrict = 'A'
  priority = 1
  terminal = true
  scope    = 
    condition: '='
    fallback: '&'

  link = (scope, elem, attrs) ->
    $compile(elem.contents())(scope) # Terminal breaks translate, this is a workaround
    elem.on 'click', (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
      if attrs.condition
        if attrs.ngClick then scope.$eval attrs.ngClick
        if attrs.uiSref
          params = scope.$eval olString.objFrom attrs.uiSref
          state = olString.until attrs.uiSref, '('
          $state.go state, params
      else
        scope.fallback()


  ######### Config #########
  restrict: restrict
  priority: priority
  terminal: terminal
  scope: scope
  link: link
```